# Regression of Results by Subgroup used to Predict using New Data using R

Tags: r, lm

I have a large data file (LMTESTData) that contains internal data and the results of an external assessment. Rather than manually subset, I have tried a number of variants on By and ddply to run a linear regression without success.

```
colnames(LMTESTData)
 [1] "StudentNumber" "SubjectCode"          "SubjectName"          "ExamMark"    "AssessmentMark"   "U"                "hmkk"            
 [8]  "TESmk"  "Year"
```

The regression model is `lm(hmkk ~  ExamMark + AssessmentMark)` for each SubjectCode .

Once the model is working, my next challenge will be to predict hmkk given SubjectCode, ExamMark and AssessmentMark for each StudentNumber.

Dummy Data Set

```
LMTESTData = data.frame(StudentNumber = 1:100, SubjectCode = c("A","B","C","D","E"),hmkk=rnorm(mean=72, 100),
                ExamMark=rnorm(mean=62, 100),AssessmentMark=rnorm(mean=68, 100))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classic R lapply-split and if you were delivering just the coefficients (or perhaps `predict()`-ions) it could be with `sapply` delivering a matrix:

```
lapply( split(LMTESTData, LMTESTData$SubjectCode) ),
         function(d) lm(hmkk ~  ExamMark + AssessmentMark, data=d) 
         )
```

Comment: Fantastic, I had been trying lapply but had a syntax error. I'm still learning,  for some NEWDATA that has ExamMark, AssessmentMark and SubjectCode, what is the easiest way to produce a table with the hmkk estimate?

Comment: If you have a desire for application of a model to new data, then the `predict` function provides such.

Comment: I was struggling with how to match against subject code when calling predict. Used data.table and this line: `NewStudents [, TES_EST := predict(lm(hmkk  ~  ExamMark + AssessmentMark, data = LMTESData [.BY]), newdata=.SD),by = SubjectCode]`

Comment: The subject code was using a dataframe. The `:=` function is for data.tables.